# Mysql Append table to add columns

Tags: mysql

I like to append a table to add column but without using `alert table` command

e.g.

This is the table which is missing some columns.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `lastVisit` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modifyAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So if i run this query then it should automatically add missing columns into my tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `originalUser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `lastVisit` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modifyAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Can this be possible to do without using `alert table` command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question as you want to add some columns to your table. Please be informed that the term *row* is usually related to the actual data in your table, not the columns itself. If my assumption is wrong, please clarify your question.

You cannot use [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) for *altering* a table. It is there to create table, 
and if it cannot create it, it will in most cases throw an error like you described. Another command exists for that reason: [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

You might do it something like this.

(1) Create your table with your [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) syntax above:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `passwd` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `lastVisit` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `modifyAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(2) Use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) like this to make the modifications I think you want to have in your second statement (two more columns):

```
ALTER TABLE
ADD COLUMN `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL AFTER `passwd`,
ADD COLUMN `originalUser` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0' AFTER `name`;
```

Not related to your question, but I'd avoid column names like `name`, because if you don't escape them properly it'll throw you other errors (see [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)).

Comment: I have a database with lot of tables where I add new columns but they are too many to go through each one of them to add it as alert table. i was hoping i can import the .sql file into database and it can think that these column are missing so i can add them in for you. what about somthing like replace table command

Comment: How many are too many? You can use dynamic SQL I guess, to go through all tables in a database and do some actions (like `ALTER TABLE`.)

Comment: If you're missing columns, you have to add them like I described. There is no `replace table` command.

Comment: thank you for all this information i was just wondering if this can be possible.